# Class hierarchy in a REST method

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, resteasy

In my REST API I get an JSON object in a POST request @ "api/register" which can be

```
{"role": "customer", "firstname": "something"}
```

or

```
{"role": "dealer", "firstname": "something", "taxnumber": "1234"}
```

So a `Customer` is a subset of a `Dealer`, a `Dealer` is specific and contains every attribute a `Customer` has and more.

I can't figure out the class hierarchy. Normally, I would just do the following:

```
class Dealer extends Customer
```

but this doesn't work with my REST method:

```
@POST
public Response create(Customer c)
```

I could write a interface which both implement but this seems artificial. Any better ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class hierarchy is fine. I think you need to adjust your API design. Having an API end point that can POST two kinds of resources is confusing.

Have something like `api/customers` mapped to:

```
@POST
public Response create(Customer c)
```

And `api/dealers` mapped to:

```
@POST
public Response create(Dealer d)
```

This is clearer and more flexible.